# Ajax button call yii pagination click event

Tags: ajax, yii, pagination

I'm just learning Yii a few days ago to developer a website for company. Now i have some issue with Yii pagination and i really need your help.

Currently i can make Yii pagination. However, i need to create a button besides pagination area. Everytime, i click that button, it will call ajax to load next page or previous pages (if  current page is last page).

**Here is my model:**

```
public function getListDesc()
{
    $arrPlace = array(0 => '--- --- --- ---');  
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select='t.*,pi.path path';
    $criteria->join='JOIN places_images pi ON t.id=pi.places_id';
    $criteria->group = 't.id';
    $criteria->compare('t.deleted', '<>1', false);
    $criteria->compare('t.status',1);
    $criteria->compare('outlet','Outlet 1');
    $criteria->order = 't.id DESC';
    return new CActiveDataProvider('Places', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 2
        )
    ));
}
```

**Here is a part of my index page which is call that model:**

```
<?php                               
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
       'id' => 'places-list-right',
       'dataProvider'=> Places::model()->getListAsc(),
        'summaryText'=>'',
        'pager' => array(
        'header' => '',
        'prevPageLabel' => '<<',
        'nextPageLabel' => '>>',
        ),                       
      'itemView'=>'_fea_oulet',)
    );
?>
```

**Here is _fea_oulet.php file:**

```
<div class="place_img" id="<?=$data->id?>">
        <div class="plusimage">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="randnew();">
                <img alt="<?=$data->id?>" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/9life-show-more-images.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0;-webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius:0">
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php echo CHtml::image("timthumb.php?src=".$data->path."&w=294&h=294&zc=1&q=100",$data->title);?>
        <div class="featitle">
            <h3><span><?php 
                    if(strlen($data->title) > 30) {
                        echo CHtml::encode(mb_substr($data->title,0,30,'UTF-8')) . '...';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo CHtml::encode($data->title);
                    }
                ?></span>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="plusinfo"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/9life-show-more-green.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0;-webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius:0"></a>
            </h3>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Any help are appreciates.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [CLinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager) class and use your own implementation `MyLinkPager` in your `CListView` widget's call specifying its [pager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#pager-detail) property like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'id' => 'places-list-right',
    'dataProvider' => Places::model()->getListAsc(),
    'summaryText' => '',
    'pager' => array(
        'class' => 'MyLinkPager',
        'header' => '',
        'prevPageLabel' => '<<',
        'nextPageLabel' => '>>',
    ),                       
    'itemView' => '_fea_oulet'
));
```

`run()` method of `CLinkPager` is the place where pager buttons' rendering happens so you can override this method directly. Or you can override [createPageButtons()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager#createPageButtons-detail) method by adding your custom button to `$buttons` array if you want to see it along with other page buttons.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing. Thanks Ezze